# Grails JMS Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-jms

I am using grails 2.4.3 version and latest grails jms plugin.

I have a durable subscription and message listener configured.

When i deploy the code to 2 node cluster, it throws javax.jms.JMSException: Duplicate durable subscription detected.

Is there a way to handle this error? shared durable subscription is part of JMS 2.0 spec.